# Dual booting when there is a breaking database change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, next-rails

I am upgrading an app from `6.0` to `6.1`, using the `next_rails` dual boot gem. As part of the upgrade I needed to execute `rails active_storage:update` which adds a `service_name` to the `ActiveStorage::Blob` table. When I run my tests with `next rspec spec` this works fine, but `rspec spec` fails with tests that use `active_storage` with messages like

```
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation:
        PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "service_name" violates not-null constraint
```

Is there a way of adding some conditional code (if `Rails::VERSION::MINOR`) that detects the version is `6.0` and somehow removes the null constraint for the `service_name` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches.

Migrate down to the version before the update:

```rb
if Rails.version == "6.0.0"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.migrate(20220816031332)
else
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.migration_context.migrate
end

# or maybe invoke the db:migrate tasks instead
```

You might need to turn off pending migration check: `config.active_record.migration_error = false`

This approach is general and should work with any migration(s).

---

The second approach is to call migration helpers manually. This is specific to the problem posed in this question and just changes the columns without updating migration version in the database:

```rb
if Rails.version == "6.0.0"
  ActiveRecord::Migration.change_column_null(:active_storage_blobs, :service_name, true)
else
  ActiveRecord::Migration.change_column_null(:active_storage_blobs, :service_name, false)
end
```

The code can be placed in `config/environment.rb` after `Rails.application.initialize!`. If you wish to place it earlier, you would need to [establish the connection](https://api.rubyonrails.org//classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionHandling.html#method-i-establish_connection) to the database manually.

Note that both methods cause persistent changes to the database, e.g. will remain after the tests have run. The changes only affect the database of which ever environment the code is run in e.g. test or development.